# Can you define Static and Dynamic Language without referring to run or compile times?

Tags: javascript, html, css, definition

I'm trying to define **static** and **dynamic** programming languages in a simple way. In the context of HTML, CSS and  JavaScript, without referring to the compile or run time.

Is it incorrect to say that

Static languages can only be updated when you update the source code.

Dynamic languages enable you to update content rendered to a webpage via the actual webpage.

Please let me know if I'm understanding it correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between static and dynamic programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563433/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-programming-languages)

Comment: I can't make out what you mean by "static" and "dynamic" above relative to the technologies you've mentioned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No dear, this is wrong.
Static and dynamic refers to types or variables, not the whole language itself.
Plus, CSS and HTML are not real programming languages.

You could read this [Difference between static and dynamic programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563433/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-programming-languages) and find much more googling