# XML to List converter? Is XML the right tool anyway?

Tags: c#, php, xml

i'm coming from PHP to C#, so please excuse some of my terminology.

Currently i'm working on a small project that requires multiple profiles to be stored in one single file, so i decided to use XML, because INI files (usually my go to guy for text based stuff) are not really supported by C#. At least not in a satisfying way.

Here the basic structure of my XML file:

```
<profile name="FooBar">
    <btnA pressed="actionA" released="actionB" />
    <btnB pressed="actionX" released="actionY" />
    ...
</profile>
<profile name="XYZ">
    <btnA pressed="actionA" released="actionB" />
    <btnB pressed="actionX" released="actionY" />
    ...
</profile>
```

In PHP i would generate an associative array with the following structure:

```
<?php
  foo = array(
    'FooBar' => array(
      'btnA_pressed' => 'actionA',
      'btnA_released' => 'actionB'
      // ...
    ),
    'XYZ' => array(
      // ...
    )
  );
```

**EDIT START**

Application Class Structure:

- Settings (Contains all profiles and a reference to the current profile)
- Profile (See below)

The `Profile` class:

```
public class Profile 
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this._name = value;}
    }

    private string _btnA_pressed;
    public string BtnA_Pressed { get; set; }
    // and so on...

    public Profile(var data) { // arg is a placeholder
        // associate the data with the properties
    }
}
```

In short, the Settings class holds all profiles and a reference to the selected profile. Access to the profile goes over Settings.CurrentProfile.propertie_Name()

**EDIT END**

The question is now, how do i achieve the same or a similar thing in C#? Or are there better methods of achieving the same thing?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `INI files are not supported in C#` - welcome to the 21st century. Please be notified that it's not 1990 anymore =). Just kidding. Use XML or a DataBase if your data model gets larger

Comment: @HighCore I love things simple and user friendly. INI's are simple and user friendly. At least up to a point.

Comment: `INI's are simple and user friendly` - until you need to represent and store any type of hierarchical data or nested data structures or even related data such as the `Person -> Address` example in my answer ;)

Comment: I totally agree on that point, that's why i chose a different approach to this than my usual way of dealing with stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to PHP where you might be used to doing a lot of arrays and [magic-string based](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) stuff, C# is a [**Statically Typed**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517670/643085) language where it's usually recommended to create a proper, formally defined, structured [**Data Model**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model) which allows you to manipulate the Data you're dealing with in a strongly typed manner.

This means, for example, that if you're dealing with personal information related data, and you need to deal with the concepts of *last name*, *first name*, and *age* you will want to create a class containing these pieces of data in the form of [**Properties**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), like so:

```
public class Person
{
    public string LastName {get;set;}

    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    public int Age {get;set;}

    //And so on...
}
```

Notice how each property has an adequate [**Data Type**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx) that allows you to *constrain* what values it can contain. For example, the fact that the `Age` property is of type `int` (integer numbers) automatically means you can **never** have something like `"abc"` inside it, and code like this:

```
var person = new Person();
person.Age = "abc";
```

will also produce a compile-time error, rather than blowing up at run time, or producing any sorts of inconsistencies in stored data.

Likewise, if your `Person` objects (in the real world data you're trying to model) have a relation to, say an *Address*, you're also going to create the `Address` class:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Line1 {get;set;} 

    public string Line2 {get;set;}

    public string City {get;set;}

    //And so on...
}
```

And then model this `Person -> Address` relationship by creating an additional property in the `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
   //.. All of the above.

   public Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

Which can be illustrated with a diagram like this:

[image]

This approach has the following advantages:

- It provides [Compile Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time) checking for correctness of the code. Compile-Time errors can be trapped (and need to be corrected) very early in the development cycle. For example, you can't do something like:

`person.LatsName` where the property name `LastName` is mispelled `LatsName` because the compiler "knows" there is no such property in the object model and thus you recieve a compile-time error rather than having the application crash at run-time.

- It provides IDE support for features such as [AutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) because the IDE "knows" the object model you're dealing with and thus it knows what properties/methods/events (Members) every class has, and what are the expected parameters and data types for each of these.

So, to answer the overarching question, once you created a proper object model, you can use .Net's built-in [**Serialization/Deserialization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(v=vs.110).aspx) mechanisms to transform instances of classes in your object model (with actual values and properties) to a data format that can be stored in a file on disk, such as XML.

Comment: Never thought of the serialization way, because my mind is still in PHP mode. Where i had to do stuff by hand, for most of the time. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

XML structures can be manipulated very easily with [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) without the need of typed models (classes).

Reading XML file containing many `profile` nodes (and i assume your XML file is correct and has one root node), can look like this:

```
// read existing XML structure
var xml = XDocument.Load("d:\\temp\\xml\\profile.xml");
// take all profile elements
var profiles = xml.Root.Elements("profile").ToList();
foreach (var profile in profiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(profile.Attribute("name").Value);
    // find all button elements
    var buttons = profile
                    .Elements()
                    .Where (e => e.Name.ToString().StartsWith("btn"));
    // list elements
    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        // tag name
        var name = button.Name.ToString();
        // attributes
        var pressed = button.Attribute("pressed").Value;
        var released = button.Attribute("released").Value;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - P'{1}' - R'{2}'", name, pressed, released));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
FooBar
btnA - P'actionA' - R'actionB'
btnB - P'actionX' - R'actionY'
XYZ
btnA - P'actionA' - R'actionB'
btnB - P'actionX' - R'actionY'
```

Reading a single profile XML structure from a `string` and then creating a new one can look like this:

```
var xmlCode = @"<profile name=""FooBar""><btnA pressed=""actionA"" released=""actionB"" /><btnB pressed=""actionX"" released=""actionY"" /></profile>";

try
{
    // read existing XML structure
    var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlCode); // XDocument.Load("c:\\path\\to\\file.xml");
    // find all button elements
    var buttons = xml.Root
                     .Elements()
                     .Where (e => e.Name.ToString().StartsWith("btn"));
    // list elements
    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        // tag name
        var name = button.Name.ToString();
        // attributes
        var pressed = button.Attribute("pressed").Value;
        var released = button.Attribute("released").Value;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - P'{1}' - R'{2}'", name, pressed, released));
    }
    // create xml
    // root element
    var newXml = new XElement("profile", new XAttribute("name", "FooBaz"), 
                    new XElement("btnA", 
                        new XAttribute("pressed", "actionX"), 
                        new XAttribute("released", "actionXR")),
                    new XElement("btnB", 
                        new XAttribute("pressed", "actionZ"), 
                        new XAttribute("released", "actionZR")));
    Console.WriteLine(newXml.ToString());
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

The output is:

```
btnA - P'actionA' - R'actionB'
btnB - P'actionX' - R'actionY'
<profile name="FooBaz">
    <btnA pressed="actionX" released="actionXR" />
    <btnB pressed="actionZ" released="actionZR" />
</profile>
```

You can use LINQ2XML to read the data and fill a list of objects of your `Profile` type like this:

```
// read existing XML structure
var xml = XDocument.Load("d:\\temp\\xml\\profile.xml");
// take all profile elements
var profiles = xml.Root.Elements("profile").ToList();
var listOfProfiles = new List<Profile>();
foreach (var profile in profiles)
{
    var profileObject = new Profile("");
    profileObject.Name = profile.Attribute("name").Value;
    // find all button elements
    var buttons = profile
                    .Elements()
                    .Where (e => e.Name.ToString().StartsWith("btn"));
    // list elements
    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        // attributes
        var pressed = button.Attribute("pressed").Value;
        var released = button.Attribute("released").Value;
        profileObject.BtnA_Pressed = pressed;
    }
    listOfProfiles.Add(profileObject);
}
```

You can also use [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - you need to describe your XML structure as a class (typed model) and *deserialize* (read XML file into your class) resp. *serialize* (write your XML structure to a file). A generic implementation of the methods for serialization resp. deserialization can look like this:

```
public void SerializeModel<T>(string fqfn, T entity)
{
    var xmls = new XmlSerializer(entity.GetType());
    var writer = new StreamWriter(fqfn);
    xmls.Serialize(writer, entity);
    writer.Close();
}

public T DeserializeModel<T>(string fqfn)
{
    var fs = new FileStream(fqfn, FileMode.Open);
    var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    var r = (T) xmls.Deserialize(fs);
    fs.Close();
    return r;
}
```

The typed model that describes your `Profile` class and the lists contained within, looks like this (note the usage of the different [XML serialization attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
public class Profiles
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Profile")]
    public List<Profile> Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName="Buttons")]
    public List<Button> Buttons { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Name;
}

public class Button
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Pressed { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Released;
}
```

Creation of an XML file:

```
    var profiles = new Profiles();
    var profileA = new Profile();
    var profileB = new Profile();
    var buttonA = new Button();
    var buttonB = new Button();

    profileA.Buttons = new List<Button>();
    profileB.Buttons = new List<Button>();
    profiles.Profile = new List<Profile>();

    profileA.Name = "Profile A";
    profileB.Name = "Profile B";
    buttonA.Pressed = "Pressed A";
    buttonA.Released = "Release A";
    buttonB.Pressed = "Pressed B";
    buttonB.Released = "Release B";

    profileA.Buttons.Add(buttonA);
    profileB.Buttons.Add(buttonB);
    profiles.Profile.Add(profileA);
    profiles.Profile.Add(profileB);

    var xmlFile = "d:\\temp\\xml\\profile_model.xml";
    SerializeModel<Profiles>(xmlFile, profiles);
```

The new XML file looks like this (note, the structure was slightly modified because of the way [XML serialization in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handles arrays/lists):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profiles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Profile Name="Profile A">
    <Buttons>
      <Button Released="Release A" Pressed="Pressed A" />
    </Buttons>
  </Profile>
  <Profile Name="Profile B">
    <Buttons>
      <Button Released="Release B" Pressed="Pressed B" />
    </Buttons>
  </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

The file can be then read like this:

```
    var input = DeserializeModel<Profiles>(xmlFile);
    foreach (var profile in input.Profile)
    {
        var b = profile.Buttons.First();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", profile.Name, b.Pressed, b.Released));
    }
```

The output is as expected:

```
Profile A - Pressed A - Release A
Profile B - Pressed B - Release B
```

Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages.

IMO the answer to your question (changed a bit) `Is XML the correct approach for saving structured data to a file?` is - definitely yes! Nowadays XML is one of the standards for representing / manipulating / exchanging structured data and data generally (data kept in a string). As someone already mentioned INI files were not really meant to represent complex nested structures.

Comment: +1 for providing a different, totally valid approach and for `Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages.`

Comment: While it would never ever be my go-to language for anything else, more recent versions of Visual Basic have *especially* good support for LINQ to XML - and the language pretty much supports everything C# does (libraries, etc)

Comment: @Katana314 it is true, VB.NET has a better *syntactic sugar* regrading XML handling.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class for `profile` with all the relevant fields/properties, you can do

```
    Profile profile = new Profile();
    profile.actionA = "actionA"; // or whatever you have


    var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\Profile_as_xml.xml");

    var writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Profile));
    writer.Serialize(file, profile);

    file.Close();
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172873.aspx