# Comma operator with typeid

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, typeid, comma-operator

I was studying *[A Generic Non-intrusive Smart Pointer Implementation](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/articles/genericptr.pdf)*. I have some confusion in *section 4*. One statement is

> the expression supplied as the argument to the typeid operator is only evaluated if the result type is an lvalue of polymorphic class type.

And associated example code is:

```
template<typename T>
  void* startOfObject(T* p) {
  void* q=static_cast<void*>(p);
  typeid(q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p),*p); // This line
  return q;
}
```

AFAIU, it means `q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p)` will be evaluated if the *result type* is an *lvalue of polymorphic class type*. The *result* means the result of evaluating `dynamic_cast<void*>(p)` (I guess), so the `dynamic_cast` has to be applied in any case. The articles states (as I understand) that if `p` is not *polymorphic* then `dynamic_cast` will not be applied, but why? Before applying it, how can it be known whether the *result* is polymorphic or not? It will be helpful if someone describes in details how the full statement will be executed.

Another statement is

> There is also a problem if p is NULL – the typeid will throw a std::bad cast.

The problem I see is with de-referencing if `p` is `NULL`, not with `typeid` (although it may throw bad_typeid, but that is not because of casting). `dynamic_cast` will return a `NULL` pointer of type `void*` if `p` is `NULL`, and `typeid` should be able to deduce the type information. Is that a typo, or am I missing something?

Comment: I got `error: cannot dynamic_cast 'p' (of type 'class C*') to type 'void*' (source type is not polymorphic)` when trying to call `startOfObject` on no-polymorphic object (https://ideone.com/7TInSx).

Comment: In C++11, we have `std::is_polymorphic` so you may use SFINAE to have what you want: (https://ideone.com/h7FRTI)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a fancy trick to write essentially the following code

```
if (T is polymorphic)
  return dynamic_cast<void*>(p);
else
  return static_cast<void*>(p);
```

The trick used is that `typeid(expr)` is evaluated in one of two ways. If the compiler determines that `expr` has a non-polymorphic type, it goes ahead and uses its static type. But if `expr` has a dynamic type, it evaluates `expr` at runtime. The assignment before the comma operator is therefore evaluatad if and only if `*p` after the comma is polymorphic.

The null case is complex for that reason. If T is not polymorphic, then `typeid(*p)` is replaced by the compiler at compile time, and the runtime null pointer doesn't matter at all. If `T` is polymorphic, special handling of null pointer dereferences applies, and that special handling states that a `std::bad_typeid` exception is thrown.

Comment: Then why gcc errors out with `cannot dynamic_cast 'p' (of type 'struct A*') to type 'void*' (source type is not polymorphic` ? I always thought `operator`, is nonconditional left to right...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Well, that's another problem with the "trick". (And why it's not a design pattern). You're thinking of left-to-right evaluation, which is indeed the case at runtime. But at compile time, GCC has to parse `typeid(a,b)`. It looks a bit like a function after all. That parsing is definitely not one-pass left to right. Only after GCC sees the `)` does it know that the typeid argument is an comma expression. But apparently, at that point it has already found the error.

Comment: @MSalters, "The assignment before the comma operator is therefore evaluatad if and only if *p after the comma is polymorphic" -- why? comma operator has left to right evaluation order, should not `*p` examined *after* the cast? could u plz explain?

Comment: @RakibulHasan: The evaluation order matters only _if you actually evaluate anything_. That simple.

Answer (score 5):

The comma operator has left-to-right associativity and is evaluated from left to right. That means the result of the expression `q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p),*p` is `*p`. So the dynamic cast is only evaluated if the type of `*p` is polymorphic.

Regarding the `NULL` problem the standard states:

> When typeid is applied to an lvalue expression whose type is a
>   polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers to a type_info object
>   representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that is, the
>   dynamic type) to which the lvalue refers. **If the lvalue expression is
>   obtained by applying the unary * operator to a pointer and the pointer
>   is a null pointer value (4.10), the typeid expression throws the
>   bad_typeid exception (18.5.3).**

Answer (score 5):

#### Explanation

Since *C++* is a [*statically typed*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517582/1090079) language the type of every expression is known at compile-time, even in cases that involves polymorphic behavior.

Whether a certain class is polymorphic or not is known at the time of compilation, this property will and cannot be changed between program executions.

If the compiler sees that the *expr* in `typeid(expr)` will not yield a value of polymorphic class type, it will simply make *expr* *"unevaluated"*, which is equivalent of not executing it during run-time.

---

**! ! !**

It is important to note that the *expr* must still be valid, we cannot use `typeid` to potentially ignore a ill-formed expression; a compiler diagnostic must still be issued if the expression is ill-formed.

Just because the *expr* will be *"unevaluated"* does not mean that we can have it contain an ill-formed sub-expression.

```
struct A { }; // not polymorphic

...

A * ptr = ...;
typeid (dynamic_cast<void*> (ptr), *ptr); // ill-formed
```

Since `ptr` is not a pointer to a polymorphic class we cannot use it in `dynamic_cast<T>` where `T = void*`, as specified in `[expr.dynamic.cast]p6`.

---

#### Dereferencing a potential *nullptr*?

This will make `typeid` throw an exception, so it will not yield *undefined behavior* but one should be prepared to handle an exception if one uses such implementation.

> `5.2.8p2` **Type identification** `[expr.typeid]`
>
> > (...) If the glvalue expression is obtained by applying the unary `*` operator to a pointer and the pointer is a null pointer value (4.10), the *typeid* expression throws an exception (15.1) of a type that would match a handler of type `std::bad_typeid` exception (18.8.3)

---

#### Clarification

> It means q=dynamic_cast(p) will be evaluated if the result type is an lvalue of polymorphic class type. The result means the result of evaluating dynamic_cast(p) (I guess).

No, what the author is saying is that if the resulting type of the **entire** expression is a polymorphic class type, than the expression will be evaluated.

<sub>**Note**: The *"entire expression"* refers to the `...` in `typeid(...)`, in your case; `q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p),*p`.</sub>

---

*The Comma Operator*

The comma operator will take two operands *expr1* and *expr2*, it will start off by evaluating *expr1* and then discard this value, after which it will evaluate *expr2* and yield the value of this expression.

- **[How does the comma operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114404/1090079)**

---

*Putting it together*

This means that the resulting type of using a comma operator is as if it only consisted of the right-hand-side expression, and in the following line the compiler will check so that the result of *expr2* is a type which is a *polymorphic class*.

```
typeid (expr1, expr2)
```

```
typeid (q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p), *p)

// expr1 = q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p)
// expr2 = *p
```

---

> <sup>**Note**: In C++03 the resulting type had to be a *polymorphic **lvalue***, in C++11 this has been changed to *glvalues* of polymorphic class type.</sup>

Comment: could u plz clarify what you meant by *entire expression*? is it `q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p)` or `q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p),*p` in this case?

Comment: @RakibulHasan The entire expression is the full expression in `typeid(...)`, ie. `q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p),*p`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

> The result means the result of evaluating dynamic_cast(p) (I
>   guess), so the dynamic_cast has to be applied in any case. The
>   articles states (as I understand) that if p is not polymorphic then
>   dynamic_cast will not be applied

`dynamic_cast` will not be applied if any of the involved types have no polymorphic relationship with each other, with the exception of being able to cast to `void*`.

Now for the whole construct, if you run it through a compiler that has good warnings, you will either see

> error: cannot dynamic_cast 'p' (of type 'struct A*') to type 'void*' (source type is not polymorphic)

or when A is polymorphic, you will see

> warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]

for

> ```
> typeid(q=dynamic_cast<void*>(p),*p); // this line
> ```

So in my opinion, *the whole line makes no sense at all*, other than to possibly prevent compilation when the source type is not polymorphic.

As to the built in comma operator that is being used here: It is being evaluated from left to right, always unconditionally, and its result is the last element. That is, the result is equivalent to

```
typeid(*p);
```

which is not being used and thus a pretty useless construct. Would it compile for non polymorphic source types in the `dynamic_cast`, then it would not be evaluated at runtime at all since the type of `*p` is known at compile time.

ISO14882:2001(e) §5.18-1

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right;
>   the left expression is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5).<sup>83</sup> Every
>   value computation and side effect associated with the left expression
>   is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated
>   with the right expression. The type and value of the result are the
>   type and value of the right operand; the result is of the same value
>   category as its right operand, and is a bit-field if its right operand
>   is a glvalue and a bit-field.

Regarding the `nullptr` issue

> There is also a problem if p is NULL – the typeid will throw a std::bad cast.

There is a special case in the standard to make this not undefined behaviour:

> If the glvalue expression is obtained by applying the unary * operator to a
>   pointer<sup>68</sup> and the pointer is a null pointer value (4.10), the typeid expression throws the std::bad_typeid
>   exception (18.7.3).

Comment: thanks for your input. I mentioned about throwing `std::bad_typeid` in my question, but my confusion was why the article says `std::bad_cast` will be thrown? is it a typo?

Comment: @RakibulHasan: I would assume so. bad_cast would be thrown would you do a dynamic_cast with target being a reference, and that cast failed.