# Throw Expected After This Token Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, token

When I run my code, it gives me an error that says, "Syntax error on token "{", throw expected after this token." The error is on line 7's code.

```
class WhileLoopTest {

  public static void main(String[] args){

  apple = 0;

  while (apple = 0) {

    (int)(Math.random( )*(60) + 5);
    return;


  }


  }

}
```

Comment: I have no idea why half the lines compile. Perhaps if you fix all the other line the error will go away.

Comment: your code wont even compile

Comment: What is apple supposed to be? I don't see it declared anywhere. `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator. And what's the point of computing a random number and not do anything with it?

Comment: yeah.  There may be some code somewhere else that is confusing it

Comment: What other errors do I have?

Comment: Is that the only code you have in that file?

Comment: `apple = 0;` doesn't compile. `while (apple = 0)` doesn't compile. `(int)(Math.random( )*(60) + 5);` won't do anything, and an unconditional `return;` in loop makes the loop pointless. The first three lines should compile. (and the `}`)

Answer (score 0):

on the line `while (apple = 0)` you are setting the variable instead of declaring it. The `while` loop expects that you pass it a `boolean`. You are probably trying to use the comparison equals `==`. The full line should read `while (apple == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra equals sign to the condition within the while statement (at the moment you are assigning the value of 0 to apple, instead of texting if it is equal), so it looks like this

```
while(apple == 0){
```

Pleas note that the while loop has no function at all, since you are returning within the loop. This will stop your program execution as you are returning from the **main** method. The computation of a random number doesn't serve a purpose here as you aren't assigning  a variable to it or printing it.

Also, you are not defining a type for the **apple** variable. Try making it of type **int**.

```
int apple = 0;
```

I suggest that you look up some tutorials on java as you seem to misunderstand several concepts within the language.

Answer (score 0):

**First** , you need to define a type for your variable apple because **Java is statically type**

```
apple = 0;
```

[Read more About Statically typed vs Dynamically typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages)

change to

```
int apple = 0;
```

**Second**, `(int)(Math.random( )*(60) + 5);` is not statement so you need to either print the value or return it

**Third**, `while (apple = 0) {` is wrong because compiler looking for Boolean expression

```
while(Boolean_expression)
{
   //Statements
}
```

change to `while (apple == 0 ) {`