# Android Bound Services: Why do we cast this IBinder instance into an IBinder instance?

Tags: android, casting, android-service, android-service-binding, android-binder

In the [developer docs for Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), the following code example is given for "Extending the Binder Class" in "Creating a Bound Service". The following code snippet (I have removed irrelevant bits) is given in which the `Service` returns an  `IBinder` from its `onBind()`method:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    ...
    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder; //**********************************************************
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in our client, we receive the `mBinder` object (which is an instance of `LocalBinder`) in the `onServiceConnected()` method of `ServiceConnection`. **My question is that why are we trying to cast an instance of `LocalBinder` passed in as an `argument` to `onServiceConnected()` into a `LocalBinder` instance in the statement `LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;` ?**

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;
    ...

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of [ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceConnected(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.IBinder)) is

> public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, **IBinder** service)

Note that the parameter is an `IBinder` - `ServiceConnection` does not know what kind of service or what kind of `IBinder` implementation the service is returning - only you know that, hence why you need to cast it to the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

Because the only type information you have in *onServiceConnected* is that you get an object of type `IBinder`. `IBinder`s don't have a *getService* method so you must perform a cast of the `IBinder` object to an object of type `LocalBinder`.  Then you can call the *getService* method.  This is how static typing works.

Comment: "A language is statically typed if the type of a variable is known at compile time. This in practice means that you as the programmer must specify what type each variable is". [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages) - Now I could not figure out how this is related to static typing.

Comment: @Zarah because casting.  You don't cast in dynamic languages (just fail). When you cast you are saying you wish to override the type information available at compile time because you know better.  You are being dynamic.