# Declare Java Class Field After Construction

Tags: java, class, field, declaration, member

In Java, is it possible to declare a new class field after the object has been constructed?

I remember being able to do so in Python using the "self" prefix:

```
def setMember():
  this.member = value
```

But, perhaps that is one of the "benefits" of not requiring pre-declared variables?

I've done a little searching around but I haven't found anything that even references the subject. Perhaps I'm not using the right key words.

Comment: No. Python and Java are different in *many* ways. This is one of them.

Comment: So Java reflection is only for introspection? We can't modify the classes on the go?

Comment: @iRaviiVooda Modification at that level would require all sorts of trickery that goes along with a compiled language. E.g. having to modify the allocated memory of every instance of that class.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There are usually other equivalents.

Comment: Although not answering your question specifically, this is question good background reading on a closely related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages

Comment: I know you said Java but have you considered using groovy and metaClass? Sounds like that would solve your problem: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClass.html

Comment: Thank you all very much. This has been informative.