# C++ use string to call object member function

Tags: c++, oop, object

I have a superclass `Entry` and subclasses `MusicAlbum`, `Book` and `Film`. Instances of these subclasses are stored according to the name of the item ie `Book1`. The name and type of all these instances are stored in a vector `cat_vector` which is a vector of objects of class `libCatalogue` which simply stores the name and type:

```
class libCatalogue{
    std::string name;
    std::string type;
public:
    libCatalogue(std::string name, std::string type);
    std::string getname();
    std::string gettype();
};

libCatalogue::libCatalogue(std::string name, std::string type) :name(name), type(type) {};
std::vector <libCatalogue> cat_vector;
```

Entries in the vector are made in the constructor eg.

```
MusicAlbum::MusicAlbum(std::string a, std::string b, std::string borrower)
    : name(a), artist(b), Entry(borrower){
    cat_vector.push_back(libCatalogue(name, "MusicAlbum"));
```

Each subclass has a member function called `printdetails()`. I want to use a loop to step through each entry in `cat_vector` and print the details of the entry but the following does not work:

```
int no = 1;
    for (auto it = begin(cat_vector); it != end(cat_vector); ++it)
    {
        std::string name_ = it->getname();
        std::string type_ = it->gettype();
        std::cout << "Entry no. " << no << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Name: " << name_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Type: " << type_ << std::endl << std::endl;
        if (type_ == "MusicAlbum"){
            name_.printdetails();     //print using MusicAlbum member function
        }
    //etc...
        no++;
```

I know it is because `name_` is a string and not an object of any of the classes I want to call, but I haven't been able to find any way to convert it so far. Is there any way to tell the compiler that `name_` is referring to an object of one  of the subclasses?

Comment: What class has print_details defined in it?

Comment: Nope,  Its a `std::string`. What is contains is irrelevant. It sounds like `libCatalogue` shoudl me a `std::multimap<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Entry>>`, or something similar. I assume `printdetails()` is virtual or pure virtual starting from `Entry`.

Comment: Each of the three subclasses has its own printDetails

Answer (score 4):

C++ is a [statically typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages) [compiled language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language).You cannot create variables on fly. Fortunately, for cases like these, the work around is to use a lookup table. Generally this is achieved through a map where the key would be the string and the value would be the function you would want to associate and call for the particular string.

> I know it is because name_ is a string and not an object of any of the
>   classes I want to call, but I haven't been able to find any way to
>   convert it so far. Is there any way to tell the compiler that name_ is
>   referring to an object of one of the subclasses?

when you qualify a member, the member name is qualified with respect to the type of the variable not with respect to the content. So the call `name_.printdetails()` would mean you are trying to invoke the member function printdetails for the instance of type std::string but std::string does not have a member function named printdetails.

A simple example to extend the above idea

```
struct Spam
{

    enum { NO_OF_FUNCTIONS = 4 };
    Spam()
    {
        lookup_callback["Foo1"] = std::bind(&Spam::foo1, this);
        lookup_callback["Foo2"] = std::bind(&Spam::foo2, this);
        lookup_callback["Foo3"] = std::bind(&Spam::foo3, this);
        lookup_callback["Foo4"] = std::bind(&Spam::foo4, this);
    }
    void foo1() { std::cout << "Foo1" << std::endl; }
    void foo2() { std::cout << "Foo2" << std::endl; }
    void foo3() { std::cout << "Foo3" << std::endl; }
    void foo4() { std::cout << "Foo4" << std::endl; }

    void call(std::string name)
    {
        if (lookup_callback.count(name) > 0)
        {
            lookup_callback[name]();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Invalid Function Call" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> lookup_callback;
};
// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    std::string name;
    Spam spam;
    for (std::cin >> name; name != "quit"; std::cin >> name)
    {
        spam.call(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I create a test object eg 'MA1' then using MA1.printdetails works not problem even though I haven't explicitly defined which member function it is

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an instance of `Entry` around than you won't have a problem because you will be able to call:

```
it->entry->print_details();
```

If you don't want `LibCatalogue` to be aware of instances of `Entry` you can create a new class called `Printable` or something similar. This class will be held by `Entry` and by `LibCatalogue`. The `Printable class will have all the details required to print. That way you could call both:

```
it->printable->print_details();
entry->printable->print_details();
```

Answer (score 0):

To augment @abhijit's answer, I often use static tables if the content is small and the usage is few.

```
// Typedef for a the function pointer
typedef void (*Function_Pointer)(void);

struct key_function_entry
{
  const char * key_text;
  Function_Pointer function;
};

void Process_Foo1_Request(void);
void Process_Bach_Request(void);
void Process_Eat_Request(void);

static const key_function_entry delegation_table[] =
{
  {"foo1", Process_Foo1_Request},
  {"Bah",  Process_Bah_Request},
  {"eat",  Process_Eat_Request},
};
static const unsigned int delegation_entries =
  sizeof(delegation_table) / sizeof(delegation_table[0]);

void Process_Request(const std::string& request)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < delegation_entries; ++i)
  {
    if (request == delegation_table[i].key_text)
    {
      delegation_table[i].function(); // Execute the associated function.
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

An advantage here is that the table is static (one instance) and constant, so it can be placed into read-only memory.  The table doesn't need to be built during runtime (like a `std::map`).  The code references a table created during compilation phase.  (It's an embedded systems thing, saving memory or placing stuff into read-only memory.)

For small number of entries, a linear search may be faster than a `std::map`.

For larger entries or very large number of accesses, an `std::map` may be preferred.