# Java method with different get and return types

Tags: java, methods

I'm new to Java and i want to write a method like this one.

```
public static double getSignum(double value){
        String signum = "";
        if(value>0){
            signum = "+"+Double.toString(value);
        }
        else{
            signum = Double.toString(value);
        }
        return signum;  
    }
```

in Javascript there is no problem to return another type...so how could i do this in java?

Comment: Why not just return a `String`? (note that it doesn't work with your code since there's a scope issue).

Comment: Indeed - it's unclear what you're really trying to achieve here - and your code wouldn't compile for other reasons, too. (`signum` isn't in scope in the return statement...)

Comment: Tunaki, what do you mean exactly? sorry I'm new...

Comment: Java is a statically typed language, while JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages. Hence Java does not allow what you want to do. The return type should be `String` if that is what you want to return. Otherwise you could still have a return type of `Object` (which would allow to return either `Double` or `String`) but this would require ugly casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to learn in Java is that its library is absolutely gigantic.

So your requirement - displaying a formatted double with an explicit plus sign if appropriate - is probably solvable using that library. That's the instinct you should adopt.

Using standard Java functions, your solution becomes:

```
public static String getSignum(double value){
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("+#,##0.00;-#");`
    return fmt.format(value)
}
```

Note that I've changed the *return type* to a `String`. Java, unlike Javascript, is a *strongly-typed* language, so you must match your function return type with the *value* you return.

I've been a bit naughty here and am using US and UK locale format for a decimal number. A lot of European countries use a `,` for the decimal separator and `.` for 1000s. Perhaps you can make what I've done more generic.

Answer (score 2):

change the method signature to

```
public static String getSignum(double value){
```

Comment: well ok! sorry this was easy.