# How can I define a variable within an object with another variable

Tags: java

The title might be a little confusing but what I want to know is how can I change
the ' b ' part in mainsave.b so that it will define it within the object.

Here is my code so far

```
public void getItem(int a, String b)
{
    mainsave.b = a;
}
```

The values are being sent from this piece of code in another class called Story.
I want them to be stored in the object of class SaveFile which is what 'mainsave' is

```
if (command_string.equals("1"))
        {
           try {Thread.sleep(1500);} catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
           System.out.println("You search the shed thouroughly and find an axe but not much else...");
           int item = 1;
           String axe = "axe";
           getItem(item,axe);
           try {Thread.sleep(1500);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}   
           area1();
        }
```

The error I get when trying to compile the first part is "cannot find symbol - variable b"

Comment: "so that it will define it within the object" - Can you elaborate, or at least use fewer pronouns?

Comment: @Zircon mainsave. b = a should come out to something like mainsave.axe = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you cannot since Java is a statically typed language. So variables names must realize at compile time.

I don't suggest but possible with reflection coding.

Comment: So would I have to create a method for each individual item that I want to pass on?

Comment: @Tristan Yes. Overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you define getters and setters for each of you fields.

Though it's not recommended, you could achieve this by reflections.

```
Object a = new A();

Class<?> c = a.getClass();

Field fieldValue = c.getDeclaredField("value");

fieldValue.setInt(a, 10);
```

[Getting and Setting Field Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)

Comment: -1, because for as trivial things as storing some data in a SaveFile class nobody should be using Reflection. (nobody should use it for non-trivial things either, for that matter)

Comment: OP could also use ASM to edit the bytecode at runtime to implement non-statically typed languages features in Java. But just because you *can* do it, doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: Don't be silly. Nobody should do something as stupid as that

Comment: sorry, kinda in a bad mood at the moment

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work since Java is a [Statically-Typed Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages) unlike *JavaScript* or *Lua*.

### So,

I would suggest you use some sort of `List` for actually storing the data instead of a lot of fields in your `SaveFile` class.