# How to reassign data types to the same variable in C++?

Tags: c++

Was wondering - is it possible to reassign data types in C++, just like in Python?

For example:

```cpp
int age = 18;
//no longer need this cached in memory...
string age = "I'm a different data type now...";
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537156/changing-variable-types-after-initialization-c hope this helps.

Comment: Recommendation: don't try to use C++ the way you would Python. You'll wind up discarding C++'s strengths and wind up with programs that will likely be inferior in most respects, including performance, to the Python version.

Comment: Good find, @AshishMJ

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? There's probably a way of solving it that's 50x simpler than using `std::variant`.