# confusion on creating class instance

Tags: java

```
class Bank{ 
    float getRateOfInterest(){return 0;}  
}  

class SBI extends Bank{  
    float getRateOfInterest(){return 8.4f;}  
}  

class TestPolymorphism{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        Bank a = new SBI();  
        SBI b = new SBI();
        a.getRateOfInterest();
        b.getRateOfInterest();
    }  
}
```

`a.getRateOfInterest()` and `b.getRateOfInterest()` both gives same output. So what is the difference between both the statements?

I think 1st is upcasting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does dynamic method dispatching work in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062344/how-does-dynamic-method-dispatching-work-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Java methods are all virtual, so the method called depends on the run-time type of the called object, not on the compile-time type of the variable holding the reference.

Comment: Oh, you beat me.

Answer (score 0):

All java method is virtual (by design).
They rely on the implementing classes to provide the method implementations.

Here is more information.
- [Can you write virtual functions / methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547453/can-you-write-virtual-functions-methods-in-java)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Here is an excerpt from wikipedia :-

```
public class Animal {
   public void eat() { 
      System.out.println("I eat like a generic Animal."); 
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Animal animal=new Wolf ();
      animal.eat(); //print "I eat like a wolf!
   }
}
class Wolf extends Animal {
   @Override
   public void eat() { 
      System.out.println("I eat like a wolf!"); 
   }
}
```

> Virtual functions are resolved 'late'. If the function in question is
>   'virtual' in the base class, the most-derived class's implementation
>   of the function is called according to the actual type of the object
>   referred to, regardless of the declared type of the pointer or
>   reference. If it is not 'virtual', the method is resolved 'early' and
>   the function called is selected according to the declared type of the
>   pointer or reference.
>
> Virtual functions allow a program to call methods that don't
>   necessarily even exist at the moment the code is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

It's not, if you construct it with `new SBI()`. It'll always return *8.4f*.