# Convert Abstract Type to Concrete Type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, type-erasure, swift-protocols, associated-types

I am trying to make Data Model for my app. here is the scenario:

my app has Customer Model which contains customer's info, and also contain his/her Payment Source. the API gives me two kind of payment sources: *card* and *bank account* which they have completely different fields.

So, here is my problem, I want to have abstract type which is PaymentSource then within each PaymentSource have a function to return object casted to it's type. some how I am type erasure.

I needed to put my abstract type in a box and use it as Concrete type (AnyPaymentSource).

So, I've done as following:

```
protocol PaymentSource {
    associatedtype Kind
    func cast() -> Kind
}

struct AnyPaymentSource<PS: PaymentSource> {
    private var paymentSource: PS
    init(paymentSource: PS) {
        self.paymentSource = paymentSource
    }
    func cast() -> PS.Kind {
        return paymentSource.cast()
    }
}

struct Card: PaymentSource {
    func cast() -> Card {
        return self
    }
}

struct BankAccount: PaymentSource {
    func cast() -> BankAccount {
        return self
    }
}

struct Customer { 
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var email: String
    var paymentSource : AnyPaymentSource<PaymentSource> 
}
```

but `Customer` gives me error with following description:

> **Using 'PaymentSource' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'PaymentSource' is not supported**

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The generic type `PS` must be a concrete type like `BankAccount` or `Card` rather than the protocol it conforms to.

Comment: @vadian then why bother create abstract type for customer's PaymentSource? i need to store payment sources without knowing what type it is. then later in code get the type

Comment: What is the purpose of these `PaymentSource` structs? As it is, you're better off going for an `enum` for the two types of payment sources.

Comment: @XmasRights true i can use enums with Generics but then later i have to use lots of switch cases. i am looking for more elegant solution like associatedtypes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift is [statically typed language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages). That means the type of a variable must be known at compile time.

When i was faced with this problem, i solved it something like this

```
protocol PaymentSource {
    associatedtype Kind
    func cast() -> Kind
}

struct AnyPaymentSource<PS: PaymentSource> {
    private var paymentSource: PS
    init(paymentSource: PS) {
        self.paymentSource = paymentSource
    }
    func cast() -> PS.Kind {
        return paymentSource.cast()
    }
}

struct Card: PaymentSource {
    func cast() -> Card {
        return self
    }
}

struct BankAccount: PaymentSource {
    func cast() -> BankAccount {
        return self
    }
}

struct Customer<T:PaymentSource> {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var email: String
    var paymentSource : AnyPaymentSource<T>
}
func test(){
    let customerWithCard = Customer<Card>(
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        paymentSource: AnyPaymentSource(paymentSource: Card())
    )
    let customerWithBankAccount = Customer<BankAccount>(
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        paymentSource: AnyPaymentSource(paymentSource: BankAccount())
    )
    print(customerWithCard.paymentSource.cast())
    print(customerWithBankAccount.paymentSource.cast())
    return
}
```

Comment: aaw thank you, i am going to mix your answer with stuff on this [blog](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasures-in-swift/)

Comment: For me, I think that there is a "code smell" here. mentioning that `cardCustomer = Customer<Card>(...` and also `AnyPaymentSource(paymentSource: Card())` doesn't seems to be alright, you are mentioning the same thing here

Comment: @AhmadF this is called Type Erasure which is even used in swift standard library (see [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2fe4254cb712fa101a220f95b6ade8f99f43dc74/stdlib/public/core/ExistentialCollection.swift.gyb#L45))

also more example you can check [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-type-erasure/) and [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasures-in-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

If what are you trying to achieve is what @Andrew Ashurov mentioned in his answer, there is no need to implement `AnyPaymentSource`. As mentioned in [Swift Protocols Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html):

> Protocols do not actually implement any functionality themselves.
>   Nonetheless, **any protocol you create will become a fully-fledged type**
>   **for use in your code**.

Meaning that are already able to treat a protocol as a *type*.

It might be:

```
protocol PaymentSource {
    func cast() -> Self
}

struct Card: PaymentSource {
    func cast() -> Card {
        return self
    }
}

struct BankAccount: PaymentSource {
    func cast() -> BankAccount {
        return self
    }
}

struct Customer {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var email: String
    var paymentSource : PaymentSource?
}
```

Creating Customers:

```
let cardCustomer = Customer(firstName: "Card Fname", lastName: "Card Lname", email: "cardemail@example.com", paymentSource: Card())

let bankAccountCustomer = Customer(firstName: "Bank Account Fname", lastName: "Bank Account Lname", email: "bankaccountemail@example.com", paymentSource: BankAccount())
```

Note that in `Customer` struct, `paymentSource` property of type `PaymentSource` which means it can assigned as any type that conforms to `PaymentSource` protocol (`Card` and `BankAccount` in your case).

Comment: when you call cast on paymentSource in customer it will return you a PaymentSource. with associatedtype i can specify which Type it should cast to. read this [blog](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasures-in-swift/) for detailed problem and solution

Comment: I think you didn't get the question exactly. The question is how to return the exact type, the object Customer still treats the `paymentSource` property as protocol, you cannot do it the way you suggested without any `associatedTypes`... That is exactly what they were meant for.