# Why new method in subclass is not accessible using superclass reference variable

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I have written below example of polymorphism.

```
package tsys;

public class DynamicPolymorphism {
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("DynamicPolymorphism");
    }
}
class AnotherClass extends DynamicPolymorphism{
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("Another Class");
    }
    public void consume(){
        System.out.println("consume");
    }
}
class TestPolymorphism{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DynamicPolymorphism dp = new AnotherClass();
        dp.eat();//Works fine
        dp.consume();//compile time error
    }
}
```

Now question is why compiler complains about `dp.consume()`? This question was asked to me in an interview I explained the reason as
"At compile time compiler only knows about Type of reference as type of `dp` is `DynamicPolymorphism` hence compiler is unable to find the `consume` method."

Interviewer counter my answer and asked what happens behind the scenes that compiler gives the error however we are referring variable `dp` to an instance of `AnotherClass`.

What else I can explains the interviewer against the counter question?

Comment: Downvoters, can you explain what is wrong with question so that I can improve?

Comment: I would have asked for clarification, because I don't understand the counter question. There is no "behind the scenes". The compiler knows that `dp` is a `DynamicPolymorphism`, so it will only allow calls it knows about, i.e. calls to methods declared by `DynamicPolymorphism`. Basically what you said. That is the fundamental nature of a [statically-typed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517582/5221149) language like Java.

Comment: @Andreas Your answer is apt, I am just looking here, Is there something that I missed regarding polymorphism. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

dp is declared DynamicPolymorphism. hence doesn't know anything about the methods of AnotherClass. If you want to call consume then you need to typecast and call consume.
try ((AnotherClass)dp).cosume()

Comment: The OP is already aware of this. Please read the entire question.

Comment: As per the contract of DynamicPolymorphism class only eat is visible. Hence type casting is must for consume to visible during the compilation.