# what decides whether an array can hold objects or not in Java

Tags: java

I have an Image class and I initialize an array as below. Here Java allow me to have only Image objects inside the images array. Why I am not able to assign string or any other values to the images array? In case of `String [] names = new String[3]` names array can hold string values. So, is there anything in the String class which will allow only string to assign to names array and we cannot assign any object to names array?

```
Image[] images = new Image[3];
public class Image {

  /** Instance variables **/
  private String imgLoc;
  private String imgDesc;
  private int dimensionX;
  private int dimensionY;
  private boolean defaultImg;

  /** Getter method for image location **/
  public String getImgLoc() {
    return imgLoc;
  }

  /** Setter method for image location **/
  public void setImgLoc(String imgLoc) {
    this.imgLoc = imgLoc;
  }

  public String getImgDesc() {
    return imgDesc;
  }

  public void setImgDesc(String imgDesc) {
    this.imgDesc = imgDesc;
  }

  public int getDimensionX() {
    return dimensionX;
  }

  public void setDimensionX(int dimensionX) {
    this.dimensionX = dimensionX;
  }

  public int getDimensionY() {
    return dimensionY;
  }

  public void setDimensionY(int dimensionY) {
    this.dimensionY = dimensionY;
  }

  public boolean isDefaultImg() {
    return defaultImg;
  }

  public void setDefaultImg(boolean defaultImg) {
    this.defaultImg = defaultImg;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's how arrays work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between statically typed and dynamically typed languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why I am not able to assign string or any other values to the images array?.

The Java type system prevents it.   An array declared with type `Image[]` can only hold objects that are `Image` instances, or instances of a subtype of `Image` (or `null` values).  The compiler will prevent you from doing that.

That is what is meant when we say that Java is a *staticly typed language*.

Furthermore, the runtime system is designed so to make it impossible to "break" the static typing rules for arrays.  For example, if you try to use reflection to put a `String` into a an `Image[]`, you will get an immediate exception.

That is what is meant when we say that Java is a *strongly typed language*.

(There are some issues to do with generic types and unsafe conversions, but even if you get that wrong the worst that can happen is that some of the hidden typecasts may result in exceptions in unexpected places.)

(The only way to actually break the type system is to step outside of the Java language;  e.g. by using native code or the `Unsafe` class.  But if you do that you are liable to make the JVM unstable, leading to JVM panics.)

> In case of `String [] names = new String[3]`, the names array can hold string values. So, is there anything in the String class which will allow only string to assign to names array and we cannot assign any object to names array?

Sure.  The type system.  The situation is the same as for your example with `Image` arrays.

But note that it is not the `String` class that is doing this ... except that `String` is a `final` class, so no subtypes of `String` are possible.

Answer (score -1):

The type of the array determines what you can put in it. Java is a [statically typed language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517670/541058).

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing that *has to be in the String class*. This is how `arrays` works.

The    `Type[] array;` will only accept `Type` instances or instances of a sub-class of `Type`

*ex for subtype*

```
Number[]array = new Number[5];
array[0] = 5;    //int
array[1] = 5.0f; //float
array[2] = 5.0d; // double
```

---

If you want to be able everything : `Object[]`