# How to return dynamic and strongly typed object from a method

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

For example in JSON.NET you can call `JObject.Parse` and it returns a `JObject` which has certain properties but if you call:

```
  dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

I can call properties on that object that don't exist on JObject.

Comment: implement the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface or inherit from a framework class that implements it like `DynamicObject` or `ExpandoObject`

Comment: Take a look at the [ExpandoObject source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Actions/ExpandoObject.cs).

Comment: You can't have both "dynamic" & "strongly-typed". They are polar opposites.

Comment: @Enigmativity exactly

Comment: @DaveM ok I'll take a look! Thanks!

Comment: @Eitan - Then what is your question?

Comment: @Enigmativity How does JObject.Parse show that it returns JObject by the framework which is strongly typed with certain properties but I can store it in a dynamic variable and call properties reflecting the jsonString.

Comment: because it implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`

Comment: @Eitan - I see. Once you assign it to `dynamic` it's no longer a strongly-typed object. It's doing run-time binding even on the strongly-typed elements of the object. Your question is probably more about how dynamic dispatch works.

Comment: @DaveM I'll have to read more about it but if you add it as an answer, I'll mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calls to properties via `dynamic` are still [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), but they are not [statically typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages) (in contrast to most of C#, which is).

That is to say, I **can't** create a class like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
dynamic myClass = new Test { Name = "John" };
myClass.Age = 30;
```

The `myClass.Age = 30;` line will compile successfully, but will throw an exception at runtime. This is because the underlying object is still *strongly typed* and doesn't implement a property `Age`. Using `dynamic` doesn't take you away from that, it just moves the responsibility of checking the types from the compiler to the runtime.

OK, now why does this work?:

```
dynamic myClass = new ExpandoObject();
myClass.Name = "John";
```

Well, `ExpandoObject` has a special interface: `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`. This allows the runtime to examine the object for additional (runtime-created) properties, methods, etc. and then get and set those values, be they values in memory or delegate methods, etc.

This is how `dynamic test = JObject.Parse(jsonString);` allows you to access JSON elements in the same way you would a concrete class in your application. The runtime simply consults the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface for the property you requested.

You can read more about implementing your own dynamic object [here](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/10/08/c-4-0-implementing-a-custom-dynamic-object/).