# How to increase the performance of reacting project with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm just started using typescript in my react project but I'm finding difficulties to identify the actual use of typescript.

Comment: Typescript doesn't increase performance. Not sure why you came up with that idea. If you don't find it useful, don't use it.

Comment: When used with React: a performance benefit might be that it renders the [prop-types](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types) library obsolete. Aside from that, the primary advantage of using TypeScript is the access to [static typing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517670/5566355) that it provides, which reduces the complexity of building applications by magnitudes.

Comment: Thanks @arman charan I just want to  how  can I effectively use typescript over  javascript

Comment: By practising. VSCode has a lot of helpful tools. It'll become pretty evident whether TypeScript is for you after your first project. [Static Type Checking - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html) is typically a good place to start @su_sundariya