# Why cannot reach derived class's member function using a base class pointer in C++? What's the design idea of it?

Tags: c++

Using the base class pointer can reach the derived class content, in general,I think. Maybe I think it is like a train, as long as I find the head of it，I can reach all of them which is public.

However, when I try to do something like this, I got an error that the base class cannot find the derived class's member function. Although I use a base class pointer variable to record the derived class address, I think it can also reach derived class member function with the head of train. While the fact proved it cannot. So I wonder what the design idea of it. Why it is designed not like Python can do? What is the advantage of this design idea?

**The error is prompted as blow:**
[image]

**Sketch map:**

[image]

**Demo code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class B{
public:
    void helloB(){
        cout << "hello B" << endl;
    }
};


class C:public B{
public:
    void helloC(){
        cout << "hello C" << endl;
    }
};

class A{
public:
    B* t;
    void helloA(){
        t->helloC();
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    C c;
    a.t = &c;
    a.helloA();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why?

C++ is *statically* typed language.  That is, it does type-checking at *compilation* time, not at runtime.

At compilation time, the compiler has no way of knowing that `t` (which it knows to have type `B*`) has a `helloC` method.  The language is trying to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot by invoking undefined behavior if the method doesn't exist.

In contrast, Python is a *dynamic* language that does not have static type checking.

[There are tradeoffs from static- vs. dynamic-checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages).  Dynamic-checking is more flexible but usually means that you can't catch some errors unless you exercise all code paths at runtime.  Static-checking helps catch errors *early* and allows for better optimized (i.e. faster) code.  For example, when invoking `A::helloA`, if `B::helloC` existed, your program would not need to check first whether `t` has a `helloC` method; it would already have been proven at compilation time.

C++ is statically typed because its target audience are developers who want to optimize for speed.

## In C++, what can you do instead?

To avoid this in C++, you instead must push your interface into the base class and make it a *virtual* method or perform a *downcast* to force a pointer (or reference) to a base class to be treated as a pointer/reference to the derived class.  In this case, you *could* use `static_cast`:

```
void helloA(){
    static_cast<C*>(t)->helloC();
}
```

which tells the compiler that you know *with absolute certainty* that `t` is actually a `C*`.  This will add no runtime overhead, but no runtime overhead also means that there is *no* runtime checking that `t` is actually a `C*`.

A more general way to downcast is to use `dynamic_cast`:

```
void helloA(){
    C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(t);
    if (c != null) {
      c->helloC();
    }
}
```

which will check at runtime whether `t` is actually a `C*`.  Runtime checks have a runtime cost, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler doesn't know anything about the object in question other than it's an instance of class B. You could have some other classes derived from B and they will fit everywhere class B can fit. Consider this: class B is more general thing (let's say an animal), while class C or any other class derived from B is some kind of animal. Let's say a dog or a bird. Let's assume all animals can make a noise, but only birds can lay an egg. Now you can have a set of animals and tell them all to make a sound, but you can't tell all of them to lay an egg. The compiler doesn't have an idea of egg-laying animal on this abstraction level. In your code the compiler can't be sure you're talking about an instance of class C.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you need to read a bit about inheritance in c++ or at least difference between c++ and python for inheritance.

From your example, it looks like you are asking a dog say Meow :D

Answer (score 0):

Class C inherits from class B, not the other way, so method helloC, which is from class C, can't be called from an object of class B.