# Polymorphism Object String

Tags: java, polymorphism

I didn't get to understand the polymorphism.

taking this example :

```
Object o = new String ("foo");
```

I can't do

```
o.substring (1,2)
```

can anyone explain this problem to me ?

Comment: Because the variable `o` is of type `Object`, which has no method called `substring`.  That variable may *reference* an in-memory object of a different type, but the variable *itself* expects to be of type `Object` and nothing more.  As an example, if you know something is a `Car` but you don't know what *kind* of `Car` it is, you can't guarantee that you can interact with specific options on that `Car` because it may not have those options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which states (summarized):

> If S and T are objects, and T is a **subtype** of S, then T may be used where S is expected.

`String` **is-a** subtype of `Object`, so if your assignment operation expects `Object`, then it will happily accept `Object` or any of its subtypes.

(Note:  `Object` **is not a** `String`.  All `String`s are `Object`s, but not all `Object`s are `String`s.)

This doesn't mean you get access to *any* of the subtype's methods.  Given the inheritance hierarchy, an `Object` has no clue about any of its children's specific methods, nor can it - there is no way to inform an ancestor class of its descendant's capabilities.  Because `Object` has no `substring` method associated with it, your code correctly results in a compilation failure.

(And it should, given that `Object` is the ancestor of *all* classes. There's no guarantee that any given `Object` is a `String`.)

The standing advice is to not use an overly *inspecific* object type (as you go up the hierarchy chain, the capabilities become less specific - you lose functionality as you go up to `Object`) to accomplish something specific to a more specific type.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing [dynamic and static typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages) with [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used).

Java is a statically typed language so the compiler recognizes that `Object` doesn't have a `substring()` method and throws an error. Polymorphism happens after the compilation, when the code is actually executed.

Answer (score 1):

First thing It's not polymorphism.

In Simple way, In your case `o` object will only call methods which are defined in Object class. If `String` class has overridden any method of `Object` class then object `o` will execute that method of `String` class otherwise Object `o` will call Its own method.

For example :

`substring()` method is only defined in `String` class So In this case your code will throw exception, however if you call `equals()` , `hashcode()` , `toString()` methods (as these are defined in `Object` class ) then definition inside `String` class will get executed because `String` Class has overridden these methods. And if any of the methods from object Class has not been overridden in its child class then definition inside Object class will get executed.

Answer (score 1):

`substring` is from the `String` class, not the `Object` class.  So the below code will work:

```
String o = new String ("foo");
o.substring(1,2);
```

This code will not work:

```
Object o = new String ("foo");
o.substring(1,2);
```

Since `String` inherits from `Object`, `String` can call `Object`'s methods, such as `toString`.  However, `Object` does not inherit from `String`, so an `Object` cannot call `String`'s methods, such as `substring`.