# C# LINQ query on anonymous types containing dynamic list

Tags: c#, list, linq, dynamic, anonymous-types

I have a piece of C# code where I have created an *anonymous type* object as follows:

```
    var measurementUnits = new List<dynamic>() {
    new { Unit = "SQF", Display = new List<string>() { "F", "FT", "SQ FT" }, Ratio=1.5 } ,
    new { Unit = "Hectares", Display = new List<string>() { "H", "HEC"} , Ratio=2.5},
    new { Unit = "Acres", Display = new List<string>() { "AC(TO)" } , Ratio=3.5},
    new { Unit = "SQM", Display = new List<string>() {  "M", "SQ M"}, Ratio=4.5 }
};
```

Through LINQ I want to access the ***Ratio*** where **Display="HEC"** (case-insensitive) something like:

```
var multiplier = measurementUnits.Where(m => m.Display == "HEC").First().Ratio;
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `dynamic` here at all? I don't see anything dynamic in what you're doing... why not just create a list of the anonymous type, and keep all the benefits of static typing?

Comment: Btw, "H" or "HEC" . You code and description doesn't quite match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to avoid `dynamic` keyword. Try this code

```
var measurementUnits = new [] {
    new { Unit = "SQF", Display = new List<string>() { "F", "FT", "SQ FT" }, Ratio=1.5 } ,
    new { Unit = "Hectares", Display = new List<string>() { "H", "HEC"} , Ratio=2.5},
    new { Unit = "Acres", Display = new List<string>() { "AC(TO)" } , Ratio=3.5},
    new { Unit = "SQM", Display = new List<string>() {  "M", "SQ M"}, Ratio=4.5 }
};

var multiplier = measurementUnits.Where(m => m.Display.Contains("HEC")).First().Ratio;
```

Also it would be better to replace `First` with `FirstOrDeafult` and manually test it for null, to avoid NullReference exception

```
var unit = measurementUnits.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Display.Contains("HEC"));
if (unit != null)
    var multiplier = unit.Ratio();
```

Comment: Only answer that avoids an exception if no such display is contained and also handles that case properly. But you could replace `Where` with `FirstOrDefault(..)` to make it even more concise.

Comment: @Rango thank you. I believe that we already have enough duplicates of "What is NullReference?" :)

Comment: What if I need a case-insensitive search like `Contains("HeC")` ?

Comment: @Sujoy: pass `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, then you aren't using `List.Contains` anymore but LINQ's extension method [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__)

Comment: @Rango you are wrong, I get error `No overload for method 'Contains' takes '2' arguments'`

Comment: @Sujoy. then you haven't added `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @Rango, please take little time to test it yourself, you will come to know. You should be wise enough to understand that if `.Where()` is working fine in my code then problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can put something like this (please, note, that `Display` is a collection which can `Contain` but not be equal to a single item `"H"`):

```
  // 2.5
  var multiplier = measurementUnits
    .First(item => item.Display.Contains("H"))
    .Ratio;
```

However, I recommend to use a *custom class* for this, not `dynamic` which is prone for runtime errors (what if `Display` is a `string`, not `List<string>`).

**Edit:** If there's a possibility that there's no such an item (say, `"HEC2"`) and you don't want *exception* be thrown but a default value, change `First` to `FirstOrDefault`:

```
  // 0.0 - default ratio, since "HEC2" is not found
  var multiplier = measurementUnits
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Display.Contains("HEC2"))   
   ?.Ratio ?? 0 /* Default Ratio Value Here */;
```

Comment: You get an exception if there is no such display contained

Comment: @Rango: yes, and I think it's a *desired behavior* (since `First()` is in the OP's original code)

Comment: There is also `Where(m=>m.Display=="HEC")`, so this is just pseudo code. I wouldn't draw any conclusions from there. As Aleks has said in another comment: _" I believe that we already have enough duplicates of What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?_"

Answer (score 1):

Contains would be your best option, yet static typing would be better and not using dynamic.

[What is the difference between statically typed and dynamically typed languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages)

```
var measurementUnits = new List<dynamic>() {
     new { Unit = "SQF", Display = new List<string>() { "F", "FT", "SQ FT" }, Ratio=1.5  ,
     new { Unit = "Hectares", Display = new List<string>() { "H", "HEC"} , Ratio=2.5 },
     new { Unit = "Acres", Display = new List<string>() { "AC(TO)" } , Ratio=3.5},
     new { Unit = "SQM", Display = new List<string>() { "M", "SQ M"}, Ratio=4.5 } 
};

var multiplier = measurementUnits.Where(m => m.Display.Contains("HEC")).First().Ratio;
```

Also you will need to check multiplier for `null` as your using `First` this will throw a null reference exception if no value is found, better solution:

```
var multiplier = measurementUnits.Where(m => m.Display.Contains("HEC")).FirstOrDefault()?.Ratio;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to list where Display "has" "HEC", since it is a list.
PS: It is unclear in your OP whether you want to filter by "H" or "HEC" (code and description dont match). Assuming it to be "HEC"

```
var result = measurementUnits.Where(x=>x.Display.Contains("HEC")).Select(x=>x.Ratio);
```

or
If you want the first one

```
var result = measurementUnits.Where(x=>x.Display.Contains("HEC")).First().Ratio;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
var measurementUnits = new [] {
    new { Unit = "SQF", Display = new List<string>() { "F", "FT", "SQ FT" }, Ratio=1.5 } ,
    new { Unit = "Hectares", Display = new List<string>() { "H", "HEC"} , Ratio=2.5},
    new { Unit = "Acres", Display = new List<string>() { "AC(TO)" } , Ratio=3.5},
    new { Unit = "SQM", Display = new List<string>() {  "M", "SQ M"}, Ratio=4.5 }
};
var multiplier = measurementUnits.Where(m => m.Display.IndexOf("H") > -1).FirstOrDefault()?.Ratio;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cand do this all with FirstOrDefault:

```
 var multiplier = measurementUnits.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Display.Contains("H"))?.Ratio
```