# Are there completely-generic objects in C++ like in JavaScript?

Tags: c++, object, javascript-objects, cross-language

I'm new to C++, but with some experience in Javascript.

In JavaScript, when I write:

```
var object = {};
```

I create an object that is "completely generic" in the sense that it has no members/features, but it *can* have any member we like by adding that member later.

Can I create or simulate the this kind of an object in C++?

Comment: You may want a C++ textbook - trying to convert javascript to C++ is not efficient. Check your C++ book for the chapter on **classes**. C++ is typed; you can't have an untyped object.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Though you can achieve something similar like the Javascript object with `std::map<std::string, std::variant<int, double, std::string>>`... ;-)

Comment: C++ is very complex and extremely unforgiving if you operate based on mistaken assumptions, so I'd definitely recommend starting with one of the books mentioned above.

Comment: `{}` isn't a completely generic object, it's a very specific object which has nothing in it

Comment: @MSalters: A C++ textbook will probably not tell OP what C++ _can't_ do. Also, it's not such a bad idea to convert JS code into C++. And premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Scheff: 1. What if OP wants another type? 2. What if OP wants an object-within-an-object? 3. See my answer.

Comment: @einpoklum -- Maybe the others are warning the OP of the pitfalls of trying to turn (or translate) other aspects of C++ into JavaScript without properly learning C++, or using JavaScript as a model in writing C++ code.

Comment: this question is [discussed at meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403171/839601)

Comment: @dandan78: I would argue it's less unforgiving than it used to be. The "JS-like" approach at the beginning of my answer would been rather insane to even suggest 12 years ago (although it basically feasible); now it's almost passable, though of course not a good idea.

Comment: The answer depends on what exactly you want to do with these objects. Please add more use cases to make this an answerable and useful question.

Comment: To specify and give the author a hint where to go: Questions of type "Is there feature X in C++?" are less interesting (bordering too broad) questions than "Is there feature X capable of doing Y efficiently in C++?", which can be a very interesting. Please add the Y to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer is mostly-no, you can't.**. In JavaScript, `Object`'s can be likened to a dictionary or map from keys to typed values, with both the values and their types settable at run-time.

You *can* create a dictionary of arbitrary-typed values in C++, using the type-erasure capability of [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), and strings for keys. With this approach, you can write:

```
using generic_object = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>
generic_object object;
object["foo"] = 123;
object["bar"] = [](char c) -> char { return c+1; };
object["baz"] = std::vector<int>{4,5,6,7};
std::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(object["bar"])[2] = 3 + std::any_cast<int>(object["foo"]);
```

You *can't* use plain-and-simple C++ syntax on new fields in your generic object, i.e. you *can't* write:

```
using generic_object = /* whatever */;
generic_object object;
object.foo = 123;                       // Compilation errors start here!
object.bar = []() -> char { return c+1; }
object.baz = std::vector<int>{4,5,6,7};
object.baz[2] = 3 + object.foo;
std::cout << "'a' becomes " << object.bar('a') << '\n';
```

like you may be used to from JavaScript. Instead, it would have to be:

```
struct {
   int foo;
   char (*bar)(char c);
   std::vector<int> baz;
} object;
object.foo = 123;
object.bar = []() -> char { return c+1; }
object.baz = std::vector<int>{4,5,6,7};
object.baz[2] = 3 + object.foo;
std::cout << "'a' becomes " << object.bar('a') << '\n';
```

And that's the "statically-typed" nature of C++. Or going even further, avoiding function pointers:

```
struct {
   int foo { 123 };
   char bar(char c) const { return c+1; }
   std::vector<int> baz {4,5,6,7};
} object;
object.baz[2] = 3 + object.foo;
std::cout << "'a' becomes " << object.bar('a') << '\n';
```

Use the clearly-typed approach, rather than the "dictionary-of-any's" I described above; that one would be cumbersome, slow, and frowned upon by most people.

---

See also:

*[What is the difference between statically typed and dynamically typed languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages)*

Comment: That looks like it. I think most people misunderstood what i meant when I said object

Comment: @Nikasmusicandgaming: You have to be more explicit in your questions. You could have described how you've seen C++ objects behave, and what you want to do with an object after creating it. Luckily, I use Javascript, so it's more obvious to me what you would do with an object after creating it empty - but if you want good answers don't rely on luck.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is dynamically typed whereas C++ is statically typed.

In JavaScript, as you showed in your example, you only need to write the variable name, without adding the type. After that, you can assign a string value but also an int value or a value of any other type.

Example:

```
var first;
var second;
```

In C++, you have to declare the type of the variable with the variable.

Example:

```
std::string str_value;
float float_value;
int int_value;
```