# Python multiple model files

Tags: python, django, file, class

This post is probably a bit more meta and less technical but....

I come from a background in C# and other C style languages. Been doing it a long time so old habits are hard to break. One of the hardest things about Python for me has been the lack of scope indicators for example. In C# there are curly braces and parenthesis and of course line break tokens all over the place. I get why python doesn't have them. But a thought occurred to me as I'm working on a django web app and the number of models I have is starting to pile up. So when I ask this question, it might just be a 'we've always done it this way' sort of thing on my part.

In C# every class is generally expected to be in it's own .cs file. This does resort in large applications have hundreds of those files. Personally I find it easier to late stuff in multiple files inside visual studio, for example, than I do trying to find a single class inside one huge omnibus models.py file in pycharm.

Obviously I know I can have my files any way I want. if I want hundreds of .py files with one for each class I can certainly do that.

Is there a reason why django seems to want to keep all the models in one models.py file? Is there some benefit stylistically or perhaps for performance or does it simply come down to a matter of taste?

thanks,
EK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main difference between C/C#/C++ and Python/Javascript is one is statically typed and other is dynamically typed [static vs dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages).

Because python is an interpreter language, the wrong sequence of import may cause error of "Circular Import Error". Which is not the case with statically typed language.

For Developer, to avoid this issue, it will be easy to keep models at one place and maintain the sequence of class declaration.

Also, it feels handy when all the models are at one place.

When I moved from C# to Python, it was difficult to understand this structure, but you get familiar with Django, you will get the reason automatically.